# Facing org.xml.sax.SAXParseException

Tags: java, xml, web-services, hibernate, rest

Here is the **web.xml** file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM 
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
<display-name>Restful Web Application</display-name>
<servlet>
<servlet-name>jersey-helloworld-serlvet</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>
com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer
</servlet-class>
<init-param>
<param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
<param-value>com.javacodegeeks.enterprise.rest.jersey</param-value>
</init-param>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>jersey-helloworld-serlvet</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
<property name="hibernate.dialect">
org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">
com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
</property>
<!-- Assume students is the database name -->
<property name="hibernate.connection.url">
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test
</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.username">
root
</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.password">
root
</property>
</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

**This is the error I am facing:**

> SEVERE: Parse Fatal Error at line 21 column 2: The markup in the
>   document following the root element must be well-formed.
>   org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId:
>   jndi:/localhost/JAXRS-HelloWorld/WEB-INF/web.xml; lineNumber: 21;
>   columnNumber: 2; The markup in the document following the root element
>   must be well-formed.  at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.reportFatalError(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$TrailingMiscDriver.next(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1537)    at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.parseWebXml(ContextConfig.java:1890)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1259)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:878)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:369)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5269)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>
> Mar 30, 2015 11:27:38 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig
>   parseWebXml SEVERE: Parse error in application web.xml file at
>   jndi:/localhost/JAXRS-HelloWorld/WEB-INF/web.xml
>   org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId:
>   jndi:/localhost/JAXRS-HelloWorld/WEB-INF/web.xml; lineNumber: 21;
>   columnNumber: 2; The markup in the document following the root element
>   must be well-formed.  at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.reportFatalError(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$TrailingMiscDriver.next(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1537)    at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.parseWebXml(ContextConfig.java:1890)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1259)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:878)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:369)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5269)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Comment: Are you sure your web.xml is fine? I mean there are hibernate tags in your web.xml, you have toerase them

Comment: i also want to use the hibernate configuration

Comment: Ok, You have to put you hirbernate configuration in another file, this is commonly call hibernate.cfg.xml and you need a HibernateFactory to read it and build the hibernate session, check this link http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-frameworks/hibernate-jpa/quickstart-tutorials-hibernate-jpa/hibernate-tutorial-with-eclipse?showall=&start=1

Answer (score 0):

Your (basic XML) parsing error comes from the fact that two root tags (`<web-app>` and `<hibernate-configuration>`) have been found in your document.

It looks like you have simply gathered the content of two XML configuration files, but it doesn't work like this. As stated in a comment, webapp configuration must be set in web.xml, and Hibernate is usually set in hibernate.cfg.xml.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you face an `org.xml.sax.SAXParseException` type of Exception it is better start with validating your xml. 
[This site](https://www.xmlvalidation.com/) comes in handy when you want to validate xml files either by uploading or just pasting the text.